# How to apply a function to grouped set and bind columns to existing dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to run a function on each group of a dataset, and bind the output to the existing set inside the tidyverse environment. After the example set, I've added how I do it right now, which requires splitting the set and running lapply (I want to move everything towards the tidyverse).

```
library(TTR)

test = data.frame('high'=rnorm(100,10,0.1),'low'=rnorm(100,0,0.1), 'close'=rnorm(100,5,0.1)) 

stoch(test,
      nFastK = 14, nFastD = 3, nSlowD = 3, 
      maType=list(list(SMA), list(SMA), list(SMA)),
      bounded = TRUE,
      smooth = 1)
```

Here is how it used to be done with lists:

```
    get_stoch = function(dat_) {
  
  stochs = stoch(dat_ %>% select(-ticker), nFastK = 14, nFastD = 3, nSlowD = 3,
                 maType=list(list(SMA), list(SMA), list(SMA)),
                 bounded = TRUE, smooth = 1)
  
  dat_ = cbind(dat_,stochs)
  
}

test = data.frame('ticker'=c(rep('A',50),rep('B',50)),
                  'high'=rnorm(100,10,0.1),'low'=rnorm(100,0,0.1), 'close'=rnorm(100,5,0.1)) %>%
  split(.,.$ticker) %>%
  lapply(.,get_stoch) %>%
  bind_rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plyr::ddply` to run a `split-apply-bind` method in tidyverse-like language:

```
df <- data.frame(ticker = c(rep('A', 50), rep('B', 50)),
                 high   = rnorm(100, 10, 0.1),
                 low    = rnorm(100, 0, 0.1), 
                 close  = rnorm(100, 5, 0.1))

test1 <- df %>%
           split(.,.$ticker) %>%
           lapply(.,get_stoch) %>%
           bind_rows

test2 <- df %>%
           ddply("ticker", get_stoch)

identical(test1, test2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: boom. thank you! this is a correct answer, and i'll use it, though i'm being particular and trying to do it with group_modify or something like that (to avoid the cbind in the get_stoch function). what are sundays for, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to translate your code to `tidyverse` you can use :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% group_split(ticker) %>% map_dfr(get_stoch)
```